# Equivalence classes of $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact, connected, locally connected, Hausdorff space. Considder $U_1\supseteq U_2\supseteq\cdots$ of open and non-empty connected subsets with compact frontiers such that $\cap\overline{U_i}=\emptyset$. We call two sequences are equivalent if and only if every set of one sequence contains some set of the other sequence and vice versa.

I have some troubles with the definition. For instance, consider real number with standard topology. How can we get the equivalence classes of $\mathbb R$?

John suggested $U_n=(n,\infty)$. It is not hard to see that $U_n$ is satisfied by all condition. With same argument We can see that $V_n=(\infty,-n)$ is another sequance which is not equivalent with $\{U_n\}$. Now, is there other equivalence class?

Comment: I guess you mean sequence of such open connected subsets? For example, pick $x\in \mathbb R$ and $a_i$ be any positive numbers converging to $0$. Then all seuquences of the form $U_i = (x-a_i, x+a_i)$ are equivalent.

Comment: @John, Honestly, I do not understand what he mean by compact frontiers. Furthermore, when you fix $U_i = (x-a_i, x+a_i)$, then $x\in \cap [x-a_i, x+a_i]$.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, frontier is the same as boundary. On the other hand, the condition seems weird: If $\overline U_i$ are all compact, then $\cap \overline U_i$ cannot be empty.

Comment: @John $\partial U_i$ is compact and $U_i$ is not compact.

Comment: Okay, so if $\overline U_i$ are not compact, might be the following: take any sequence $a_i \to \infty$. Then $U_i = (a_i, \infty)$ are all equivalent?

Comment: In what contexts are you reading this? Weird conditions...

Comment: It is related to ends of topology space according to google.

Comment: I see. So it is related to finding "boundaries" of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=\mathbb R$, there are only two equivalent sequences: $\{(n, +\infty)\}$ and $\{(-\infty, -n)\}$. The reason is the following:

Let $\{U_i\}$ be one such sequence. First of all, $U_i$'s are all connected. So $U_i$ has to be some intervals $U_i = (a_i, b_i)$. But as

$$(*) \bigcap_i \overline U_i = \emptyset$$

Then either $a_i = -\infty$ or $b_i = \infty$. (Or $\overline U_i$ would be compact and so are all $\overline U_j$ for $j \geq i$)

If they are both infinities, then $U_i = \mathbb R$. Thus ther exists some $i$ so that $a_i \neq -\infty$ or $b_i \neq \infty$ (or all of them are just $\mathbb R$).

If $a_i \neq -\infty$, then $b_i = +\infty$. Then $a_j \neq -\infty$ and $b_j = +\infty$ for all $j\geq i$. Using (*) again, we see that $(a_i)$ has to converge to $+\infty$. Thus $\{U_i\}$ is equivalent to $\{(n, \infty)\}$.

Similarly if $b_i \neq +\infty$, then $\{U_n\}$ is equivalent to $\{(-\infty, -n)\}$.

Let's also consider $X = \mathbb R^n$. In this case we can show that there is only one equivalent class given by 
$$\bigg\{U_n  = \{x : n<|x|\}\bigg\}_{n=1}^\infty.$$

First, let $V_i$ be an open set with compact boundary. For our consideration we assume that $V_i$ is unbounded (If $V_i$ is bounded, it is impossible that $\cap \overline V_i = \emptyset$)

As the boundary is compact, there is $n_i$ so that $|x| < n_i$ for all $x \in \partial V_i$.

**Claim** $U_{n_i} \subset V_i$.

To show this, let $x \in V_i \cap U_{n_i}$. For any $y\in U_{n_i}$, connect $x$ to $y$ by a path $\gamma$ so that $\gamma$ lies in $U_{n_i}$. In paricular, $\gamma$ does not pass through the $\partial V_i$. Thus $y\in V_i$. This finishes the proof of the claim.

So for any $V_i$, there is $U_{n_i}$ so that $U_{n_i} \subset V_i$. On the other hand, consider the set $U_n$. Let $K = \{x: |x| \leq n+1\}$. Then $K$ is compact and so are $\overline V_i \cap K$. But

$$\bigcap_{i=1} \overline V_i = \emptyset \Rightarrow \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \big( \overline V_i \cap K\big) =\emptyset \Rightarrow  \overline V_i \cap K = \emptyset$$

for some $i$. That is $|x| > n$ for all $x\in V_i$ and so $V_i \subset U_n$. Thus $\{V_i\}$ is equivalent to $\{U_n\}$.

Comment: @user108209: I have made an edit, please have a look.